# PYQT runs with out error but dont show executing browser

Tags: python, android, browser, pyqt

```
#! /usr/bin/python 3.8

from idlelib.pyshell import main
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

def browser():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser()
```

Comment: add `window.show()` after `window = MainWindow()`

Comment: That didn't work